# Pageable не работает совместно со Sort.by

Tags: java, spring, сортировка, hibernate

У меня возникла следующая проблема: при попытке вывести страницу со списком строк из удаленной бд упорядоченную по какому-то полю, я не получаю никакого ответа.

```
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@PostMapping("test")
public Page<Account> getTest() {
    Pageable pageWithHundredElements = PageRequest.of(
            0,
            100,
            Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "number")
    );

    return accountRepository.findAll(pageWithHundredElements);
}


public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Account> {}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "AA_ACCOUNT_FOR_TEST")
public class Account implements MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_1")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "A_2")
    private String clientId;

    @Column(name = "A_3")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "A_4")
    private Date closeAt;

    @Column(name = "A_5")
    private Double balance;

    @Column(name = "A_6")
    private Double actualBalance;

    @Column(name = "A_7")
    private Double partnerBalance;

    @Column(name = "A_8")
    private String partnerId;
}
```

Запрос, который генерирует hibernate:

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            account0_.A_1 as A_1_14_,
            account0_.A_2 as A_2_14_,
            account0_.A_3 as A_3_14_,
            account0_.A_4 as A_4_14_,
            account0_.A_5 as A_5_14_,
            account0_.A_6 as A_6_14_,
            account0_.A_7 as A_7_14_,
            account0_.A_8 as A_8_14_
        from
            AA_ACCOUNT_FOR_TEST account0_ 
        order by
            account0_.A_1 asc ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
```

Никаких сообщений об ошибке не получаю (вообще ничего не получаю).

Рабочий нативный запрос:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
     (SELECT 
          * 
      FROM 
          AA_ACCOUNT_FOR_TEST 
      ORDER BY A_1 ASC) 
WHERE 
   ROWNUM <= 100
```

Нерабочий нативный запрос:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
     (SELECT 
          A_1,
          A_2,
          A_3,
          A_4,
          A_5,
          A_6,
          A_7,
          A_8 
      FROM 
          AA_ACCOUNT_FOR_TEST 
      ORDER BY A_1 ASC) 
WHERE 
   ROWNUM <= 100
```

Как видно, отличаются они только указанием конкретных полей таблицы

Что пробовал:

1. использовать данный метод без параметра сортировки - **успешно**
2. написать нативный запрос к бд используя упорядочивание (order by) и вывод заданного количества строк (limit | fetch next) - **успешно**
3. использовать данный метод для других представлений из той же базы (описаны аналогично) - **успешно**
4. применить сортировку для других полей этого же класса - **неудача** (тоже никакого ответа)

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Пытался гуглить, но не нашел решения конкретно для моей проблемы.  Возможно, тупо не вижу какой-то ерунды... 
Помогите, пожалуйста) Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой

PS:
Нет прямого доступа к удаленной базе. Могу только нативные запросы на чтение кидать из кода. Но если проблема исходит со стороны базы, можно что-то придумать)

Comment: Включите логирование запросов в Hibernate и посмотрите какой запрос строится.
Включить логирование для Hibernate в Spring Boot можно так:
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

Comment: можно попробовать написать `Sort.by("number").ascending()` вместо `Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "number")` [взял отсюда](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting), хотя это одно и то же. Можно попробовать вызвать `mvn clean`, вруг ide не применяет изменения, ну и в логи смотреть как уже написали.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, уже пробовал такое, но это ничего не меняло

Comment: @OlegMarchenko, спасибо за совет. Возьму его на вооружение. Только это мне не помогло, к сожалению. Запрос отправляется аналогичный тому, что и у аналогичной сущности, только ответ не приходит. Буду копать дальше

Comment: добавьте в вопрос сгенерированный sql запрос hibernate, что там указано в order by, `number` или `A_1`?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, добавил

Comment: sql запрос, который добавили, он хоть выполняется(`?` заменить на 100) напрямую в БД? и какой запрос запрос выполняли в п.2? Есть подозрения на версию БД(оракл?),, которую используете, может синтаксис поменялся или диалект. Какая версия БД, драйвера и используемый диалект? других догадок еще не придумал

Comment: @MrFylypenko, драйвер верный (да, оракл) и с диалектом тоже экспериментировал. Добавил запросы в описание

Comment: в подзапросе у нативного нерабочего запроса должно быть еще указано поле rownum типа `SELECT A_1, rownum, ... from ...  `, не понятно, почему springdata его не формирует. Могу порекомендовать использовать entityManager, либо написать native query